# How would i be able to check for a correct answer in a quiz C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been trying to make my first app, A quiz app, and can't seem to get my head around how I would validate a correct answer when the appropriate button is clicked to then move on to the next question.

Quiz Page:

```
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // list array
    List<Question> qu;

    //counter for moving to next question
    int questionNumber;

    // correct answer counter
    int correctAnswer;


    public void main()
    {
        // method for adding more questions to the list
        qu = new List<Question>();
        qu.Add(new Question("what is your favourite colour?", 
                            "blue", 
                            "red", 
                            "green", 
                            "blue"));

        qu.Add(new Question("what is your favourite film?", 
                            "The Matrix", 
                            "Star Wars", 
                            "Wrath Of Khan", 
                            "The Matrix"));

        qu.Add(new Question("what is your favourite car?", 
                            "BMW", 
                            "VW", 
                            "Mercedes", 
                            "BMW"));
        questionNumber = 0;
        correctAnswer = 0;

    }

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        main();
        // counter for displaying next question
        displayQuestion(questionNumber);


    }

    // button for quitting back to the start screen
    private void btn_quit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        NavigationService.Navigate(
           new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void btn_Answer_A_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        endQuestion();
    }

    private void btn_Answer_C_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        endQuestion();
    }

    private void btn_Answer_B_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        endQuestion();
    }

    // method for ending a question, inc : counter for 
    // moving on to next question and
    // checking if the answer is correct or not
    public void endQuestion()
    {
        //check the answer
            //if it's correct
                questionNumber++;
                displayQuestion(questionNumber);
            //otherwise 
                //stay on question
    }

    public void displayQuestion(int counter)
    {
        // where the question and answers are displayed 
        // in the buttons and txt block
        txt_block_question.Text = counter + ". " + qu[counter].question;
        btn_Answer_A.Content = qu[counter].a;
        btn_Answer_B.Content = qu[counter].b;
        btn_Answer_C.Content = qu[counter].c;
    }
}
```

Question Class

```
public class Question
{

    public String question;
    public String answer;
    public String a;
    public String b;
    public String c;


    public Question(string q, string an, string optionA, string optionB, string optionC)
    {
        question = q;
        answer = an;
        a = optionA;
        b = optionB;
        c = optionC;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `Question` class.

Comment: These are opinion based questions, there can be no "correct" answer.

Comment: My best guess is that these are meant to be "security questions" which the user has already given the correct answer to at a previous point in time.  The OP may be trying to test the functionality before using actual user input to determine the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've displayed, I think the solution is fairly simple:

First, you will want to pass a variable to `endQuestion()`, telling it which answer was chosen.  Since each answer button has the text of the answer stored in its `Content` value, you can just pass that.

Second, you will want to update `endQuestion()` to take an "answer" parameter and compare that answer to the correct answer stored in your `Question` variable (`qu[counter].answer`).  Using [String.Compare(string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx) would be a good way to perform the comparison.

This should be all you need to get started.  I'll leave the actual code implementation to you.

Comment: thanks jon ill get on that just now and see if i can get it working.

Comment: i cant seem to pass the content variable to endQuestion()

Comment: Just update the definition of `endQuestion()` to take a string parameter and call it like so (assuming we're in btn_Answer_A_Click`): `endQuestion(btn_Answer_A.Content.ToString())`